# Can't Boot Live CD In VirtualBox UEFI/EFI Mode

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, uefi, livecd

I really need to boot into a live CD in EFI mode so I can run `update-grub2` but it keeps using BIOS mode for some reason. I set mount points and chroot to the install I want to work on and then update grub and it says `/boot/grub/grub.cfg.new: Directory nonexistent`.

I have EFI enabled in the VirtualBox settings. How can I update grub of one of my vdisks? I can't boot that disk until I update grub. I'm operating on an ubuntu install. I've tried 3 different live cds.

Comment: VirtualBox is either BIOS-only or EFI-only, depending on which firmware type you select. (BIOS is the default.) Thus, if you've changed the setting to EFI mode, that's how you're booting, and your error is caused by something else. (It's not clear from your description why you think you've booted using BIOS.) For Ubuntu installs, most people use [Boot Repair,](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) so you might try that, and post the URL to the repair results if it doesn't work.

Comment: You asked this question on [Unix and Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/379258/cant-boot-live-cd-in-virtualbox-uefi-efi-mode) as well.